# Django : How to retrieve an extra-field defined in admin for a model in a pre_save signal?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I've overloaded admin form for a model by adding an extra-field

```
class MyModelAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

The password field isn't exists in model and I don't want it to be stored automatically. 
I want to retrieve the value of this form field in the pre_save method :

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Member)
def my_pre_save_method(sender, **kwargs):
    ...
```

Actually I don't find a way to retrieve it.

Is this possible ? And How ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't full understand what you're asking here.

Anyhow, your question is far too general to answer in full. As an overview you only 'pass' **clean** form data in a **view** i.e. when you create an instance of that object. In your case this would be 'Member'.

I would suggest you start learning Django with the [tutorials](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/). They really do help, honest.

Answer (score 0):

`pre_save` is called from model's `save` and it works on form level. The field `password` is not a model field so this will not be available on the instance of model and hence you can't access it in `pre_save`.

So, you can only retrieve is in the view using `cleaned_data`, and then use it in some way you want.